# How to get realtime spawned childProcess.stdout in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I am using Node to call a command which *sometimes* returns an interactive shell prompt. And I'm using `ChildProcess.spawn` to create the subprocess.

Here's my node.js code:

```
let ps = ChildProcess.spawn('command', ['arg1', 'arg2'], { interactive: true })

ps.stdout.on('data', data => {
  console.log('GOT SOME DATA:', data.toString())
})

ps.stderr.on('data', data => {
  console.log('ERROR:', data.toString())
})
```

And my script *sometimes* has an interactive prompt like:

```
Enter Password:
```

I would like to be able to listen for this text (something like `if (line.match(/^Enter Password:/)) { ... }`, and then write to **stdin**, but `ps.stdout.on('data', ...)` doesn't get called until the process exits.

How do I flush the process's **stdout** stream and get the data right away (or even poll for it)?

**Note:** I've also tried `pty.js` and no luck, it seems to just completely stall.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine , I was just receiving a buffer and not a string , try with string interpolation :

```
let ps = ChildProcess.spawn('ls', [], { interactive: true})

ps.stdout.on('data', data => {
  console.log(`Got some data : ${data}`)
})

ps.stderr.on('data', data => {
  console.log(`Got some error : ${data}`)
})
```

Comment: You're right I forgot to add the `toString()` (or interpolation). But that's not the issue. The issue is that the data is not being received until the command exits (or a certain character limit it reached).

Comment: Hi Jeremy , if you can please share more code so that I can try to help you , in particular your 'command' is a node js script ?  . One thing that you can try to do is to set stdio to 'ipc' so that parent and child will be able to communicate with IPC communication  https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio . See this that could help you https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback .